# Explode all delimited strings in a flat array into a flat array of individual substrings

Tags: php, arrays, explode, flatten, delimited

I have a loop that contains a string of comma seperated values.

```
foreach ($profiles as $profile) {
    $user_states[] = exlpode(', ', '[string of comma seperated states]');
}
```

The problem I'm experiencing is the `$user_states` array ends up being two levels, with each iteration of the loop creating a nested array.

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'DC' (length=2)
      1 => string 'Maryland' (length=8)
      2 => string 'Northern-Virginia' (length=17)
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'North-Carolina,Virginia' (length=23)
```

How can I take exploded values and place them all into a single array?

Comment: Your problem is that `explode()` returns an array. If you assign arrays as new elements into your target array `$user_states` you obviously get an array of arrays.

Comment: initialize a main array before the loop and merge your explode to that (array_merge)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[]=` operator means add to array. `explode` method, returns an array, so what you are doing is adding an array into array.

since `profiles` probably contains 2 elements, you are getting an array of size 2 of exploded strings

what you are probably looking for is [`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

replace the inner part of the loop with this:

```
$exploded    = exlpode(', ', '[string of comma seperated states]');
$user_states = array_merge($user_states, $exploded)
```

Comment: This makes perfect sense and is what I suspected, I'm just not sure how to merge the results of the exploded string into a single array.

Comment: @Niko 100% right, i just prefer using self descriptive method names when im answering on stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this

```
$user_states = exlpode(', ', '[string of comma seperated states]');
```

**EDIT:**

If I am not wrong this code helps you

```
$profiles = array( "yale, ny, la", "boston, vegas");

$user_states = array();

foreach ($profiles as $profile) {

    $tmp = explode(', ', $profile);
  $user_states = array_merge( $tmp, $user_states);
}


var_dump($user_states);
```

Comment: This would replace the elements in the array with each iteration of the foreach() loop

Answer (score 1):

What you need is:

```
$user_states = array();
foreach ($profiles as $profile) {
  $user_states = array_merge($user_states, exlpode(', ', '[string of comma seperated states]'));
}
```

Regards,
Valentin

Comment: Thank you for the answer. While it is correct, I'm going to give the credit to Dima for his clear explanation of the situation.

Answer (score 1):

Use the merging function:

```
$states=array();

foreach ($profiles as $profile) {
    $user_states = exlpode(', ', '[string of comma seperated states]');
    array_merge($states,$user_states);
}

var_dump($states);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
$user_states = array();
...
$user_states += explode(', ', '[string of comma seperated states]');
...
```

This will keep adding the 'explode' arrays to the main $user_states array.

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't know what you have in `$profiles`, I'm giving you a simple example.

```
$user_states = array();
$profiles = array('UK, FR, CA, AU', 'UK, FR, CA, AU', 'NW');

foreach ($profiles as $profile)
{
    $extract = explode(', ', $profile);
    $user_states = array_merge($user_states, $extract);
}

// if you want to remove duplications
$user_states = array_unique($user_states);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($user_states);
```

Will give you:

```
Array
(
    [0] => UK
    [1] => FR
    [2] => CA
    [3] => AU
    [8] => NW
)
```

AND

If you don't use `array_unique()`

```
Array
(
    [0] => UK
    [1] => FR
    [2] => CA
    [3] => AU
    [4] => UK
    [5] => FR
    [6] => CA
    [7] => AU
    [8] => NW
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is indirect to bother making iterated explosions and merge calls.

Just implode the entire 1d array using the same delimiter that you explode each string with, then explode THAT single string.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/eBZ0I))

```
$array = [
    'DC, Maryland, Northern-Virginia',
    'North-Carolina, Virginia',
];

var_export(explode(', ', implode(', ', $array)));
/*
array (
  0 => 'DC',
  1 => 'Maryland',
  2 => 'Northern-Virginia',
  3 => 'North-Carolina',
  4 => 'Virginia',
)
*/
```

---

If you absolutely need to use a loop (perhaps because you are doing other operations per iteration, then don't bother merging; use `array_push()` for the only thing it is good for -- pushing multiple elements into an array at once.  Use the spread operator to allow `array_push()` to push the generated elements individually into the result array.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/tRKV4))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $string) {
    array_push($result, ...explode(', ', $string));
}
var_export($result);
// same result as previous snippet
```